# WebView not working in Sony Xperia Zee

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I am working with `WebView` , it is working fine with all versions and devices except **Sony Xperia Z** 4.3, API level 18, the url I am loading in WebView consists of some texts and images.

Code I used

**java**

```
overViewDetail = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.detail_tv);


WebSettings settings = overViewDetail.getSettings();

settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

**Xml**

```
 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/detail_tv"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="@string/overview_details"
     android:textColor="@color/colorfont"
     tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
```

**PS** : I have searched on many solutions but they didn't worked for me

*references*

[Webview content not loading all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35195301/4702912)

[Android webview javascript seems not working on Sony Xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933111/android-webview-javascript-seems-not-working-on-sony-xperia)

[Android stock browser on Xperia Z does not render html correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275036/android-stock-browser-on-xperia-z-does-not-render-html-correctly)

[android dev : is any specific multithreading coding with Sony Xperia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031047/android-dev-is-any-specific-multithreading-coding-with-sony-xperia)

Comment: On the second reference link it mentions to set: `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` after `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` Have you done this and if yes why it is not posted on your question's code?

Comment: yes i have done that but not tested yet

Comment: what is purpose of 
.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 WebView x = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.x);
 x.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 x.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 x.loadUrl("");
```

And don't forget this in Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: can u tell the reason for 

setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())

Comment: We are creating a new WebViewClient, so WebView can know.